# How can i get the position in the Array list model class in the Observer using Live Data?

Tags: android

```
Observer<ArrayList<ActionModel>> arrayListObserve=new Observer<ArrayList<ActionModel>>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(@Nullable ArrayList<ActionModel> actionModels) {
                Action1.setText(actionModels.get(position).getBackground_remarks());
            }
        };
```

here,i can get the  ActionModel class object but i can't get the position of the arraylist so how can i get the position of arraylist??

Comment: position? what position do you mean? `ArrayList` does not have any concept of "current position" or something like that

Comment: Array position of model class how can i get the position??

Comment: again, what position are you talking about?

Comment: You can use actionModels.indexOf(actionModel) to get index of your model in the arraylist.

Comment: Array position i.e ArrayList<ActionModel> actionModels. here actionModels was arraylist and i have different data in different position like 0,1,2,3,... how to access the position

Comment: there is no position: `onChanged()` callback only notifies that the whole array changed, not that some item at some position has changed, what if two items changed? would you want to get two positions?